# receive object from server and cast it to desired object in client Typescript (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, casting, javascript-objects

I have a class in typescript which is like below :

```
    export class Broker {
    constructor() {
        this.id = Guid.newGuid();
        this.stations = new Array<Station>();
    }
    index: number;
    id: string;
    name: string;  
    stations: Array<Station>;
    isIncomplete(): boolean { // error occurs because of this function which is undefined
        if (this.name == "" || this.name == undefined)
            return true;      
        return false;
    }
}
```

and an array of this class

```
brokers: Array<Broker>;
```

I get the **brokers** from server like below

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.brokers = new Array<Broker>();

    this.brokerservice.getlist().then(
        data => this.brokers = data as Array<Broker>,

        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);    
}
```

**getlist** in service returns the correct type (Array of Broker) and the json which is received from server is like below:

```
var brokers = new[]
        {

            new
            {
                index = 0,
                id = "097809098008",
                name = "کارگزاری اول",
            },
            new
            {
                index = 0,
                id = "98709-9",
                name = "کارگزاری ",
            },
        };
```

**isIncomplete() function**  is a calculated function, I can not define (or at least i do not know how) it on server side when I want to use **brokers** a on client side I got the error **isIncomplete is not a function** if I omit the function everything works fine. even if I declare the exact type of brokers array and cast it but the error occurs. what is the best way (instead of defining a global function) to solve the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if you are targeting ES6:

```
data => this.brokers = data.map(d => Object.assign(new Broker(), d))
```

If you are targeting < ES6, then you can use [this polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).